# What is supposed to be in this line? (java)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

So i get an error for this piece of code.

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.whippingsound);
```

An the errors for this line (Eclipse Ide) is:

```
The method create(Context, int) in the type MediaPlayer is not applicable for the arguments (new View.OnClickListener(){}, int)
```

Now what am i missing in the parenthesis and can you explain to me what it is? Thanks! Whippingsound is my audio and raw is the folder. Thanks Guys!

Comment: What's "this" in the code you gave us? Specifically, is it descended from the Content class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you are creating the MediaPlayer in some listener, which is an internal (anonnymous) class, which its "this" hides the Activity `this`. You need to give the fully qualified "this" as an argument, assuming your activity is called MyActivity, it should be:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MyActivity.this, R.raw.whippingsound);
```

Answer (score 3):

The first argument to create, namely `this`, is not a descendent of the class Context, so you cannot pass it to the create method.